# Ruby reverse only index but keep values in place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to loop through a result set in the order as given but only print out the index in reverse? Example:

```
items = ["a", "b", "c"]

items.each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts index.to_s + ": " + value
end
```

Gives:

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
```

**Is there a way to reverse only the index so that the output is:**

```
2: a
1: b
0: c
```

Comment: Presume you mean `items = ["a", "b", "c"]` (array `[]`, not hash `{}`)

Comment: Yes, sorry fixed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure what you want to achieve, but chaining enumerators with `reverse_each` could be useful:

```
items.reverse_each.each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts index.to_s + ": " + value
end
```

produces:

```
0: c
1: b
2: a
```

Add another `reverse_each` to get exactly the result you ask for:

```
items.reverse_each.each_with_index.reverse_each do |value, index|
  puts index.to_s + ": " + value
end
```

produces:

```
2: a
1: b
0: c
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Enumerable#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip):

```
>> items = %w{a b c}
>> (0...items.size).reverse_each.zip(items) do |index, value|
?>   puts "#{index}: #{value}"
>> end
2: a
1: b
0: c
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there's a more ruby way to achieve this as well (maybe a built in function).

Comment: @Hopstream, I added an alternative that use `Enumerable#zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply substract the index from items length, and an additional - 1 to match indices:

```
items.each_with_index { |val, index| puts (items.length - index - 1).to_s + ": " + val }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
offset = items.length - 1
items.each_with_index { |value, i| puts "#{offset - i}: #{value}" }
```